# how to change a variable in an array of struct without changing others

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to change a variable in a struct object. But every time I change it, other objects will change as well.

Here is my struct

```
    struct room{
    char * S;
    char * N;
    char * W;
    char * E;
    char  South;
    char  North;
    char  West;
    char  East;
    char * Name;
   };
```

and here is block I ran in main method

```
int numOfRooms=0;
struct room * rooms;
rooms=(struct room*)malloc(sizeof(*rooms));
do{

rooms=(struct room*)realloc(rooms,sizeof(*rooms)*(numOfRooms+1));
fscanf(fp,"%s%c",name,&temp);
printf("%s ",name);
printf("%d",numOfRooms);
rooms[numOfRooms].Name=name;
printf("%s ",rooms[0].Name);

numOfRooms++;

}while(temp!='\n');
```

and the output is: START 0START FOYER 1FOYER ELEVATOR 2ELEVATOR

which should be: START 0START FOYER 1START ELEVATOR 2START

that's my problem. Every time I try to change `Name` in my struct, the Name for previous ones change as well.
name was declared

```
char string[20];
char defa[16]="No Path This Way";
char temp;
char * input;
char * name=string;
```

Comment: You appear to be assigning the same variable to `rooms[numOfRooms].Name` so why would you expect them to have different values?

Comment: regarding: `rooms=(struct room*)malloc(sizeof(*rooms));`  1) the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, si `void*`  which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) if the declaration of rooms is changed to: `struct room * rooms = NULL;`  then the call to `malloc` can be eliminated.

Comment: regarding: `rooms=(struct room*)realloc(rooms,sizeof(*rooms)*(numOfRooms+1));`  1) don't cast the returned value (see my prior comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
rooms[numOfRooms].Name=name;
```

You're making `Name` point to the same thing that `name` points to.  It is *not* copying the value.  This means that all of your `room` instances have their `Name` member pointing to the same place.

You should use `strdup` to create a new dynamically allocated string from the one you use to read the user input:

```
rooms[numOfRooms].Name=strdup(name);
```

Be sure to call `free` on this field when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

variable `name` is not declared.

This is very likely the wrong way to assign a variable.
 *(but since you didn't show the declaration of `name`, it is hard to be sure)*

```
rooms[numOfRooms].Name=name;  // Use Strcpy, strdup, or similar.
```

Comment: char string[20];
char temp;
char * name=string;

Comment: name was delared